# Fetch data from a complex JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to javascript and JSON and I've been given a task to complete. Please find the JSON in the following link,

http://pastebin.com/0BY3eptF

According to me the above is a very complex JSON.

I'm trying to fetch the out from a WSDL via ajax

```
success: function(api) {
    console.log(api.SearchResult); // trying to fetch information on SearchResult object
}
```

This doesn't work. I would like to learn how to iterate each JSON string loop. I also see an array which is WSResult[]. A neat javascript with explanation will help me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Are you aware of JSON.parse in javascript? Or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you John Barca I did not know this before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some web services return content type as plain text instead of json, you have to manually convert into json. below code will help you do the same.

```
success: function(api) {
    if (api.constructor === String) {
        api = JSON.parse(api);
    }
    console.log(api.SearchResult);
}
```

To loop through api.SearchResult.Result.WSResult array, please find below code

```
$(api.SearchResult.Result.WSResult).each(function (index, val) {
    // here val is single object of WSResult array
});
```

Comment: Alternatively I believe explicitly specifying the dataType would ensure JQuery handles all this for you....

Answer (score 1):

`success: function(api) {}`, here, `api` is still a string, you have to parse it to JSON first:

```
success: function(api) {
    var api = JSON.parse(api);
    console.log(api.SearchResult); // trying to fetch information on SearchResult object
}
```

Comment: It's not a string if you've set dataType to JSON in the AJAX call. It should also infer this if using jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but some useful pointers:

```
$ajax({
    url: 'http://myURL',
    // specify the datatype; I think it overrides inferring it from the document MIME type
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function (api) {
        // provided your data does come back as a JSON document
        // you should be able to access api.SearchResult
    },
    error: function( jsXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // always have an error handler, so you can see how it went wrong.
    }
);
```

Read the section on [dataType](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) here, as it may solve your problem